# How to capitalize elasticsearch geoJSON (geometry) "type"

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, geojson

When retrieving an correctly indexed GeoJSON from elasticsearch the GeoJSON `type` is returned as all-lowercase;

```
"_source": {
    "ogc_fid": 205,
    "geometry": {
        "type": "multipolygon",
        "coordinates": [
            [
                [
                    [-7.431,
                        4.351
                    ],
                    [-7.442,
                        4.348
                    ],
                    [-7.466,
                        4.345
                    ],
                    [-7.498,
                        4.347
                    ],
                    ...
                ]
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

When viewed in Kibana it is clearly shown/retrieved as `"type": "MultiPolygon"`

- There is no difference in using a `term` or `match` query.

**Q:** How can I tell elasticsearch how to NOT lowercase "type" as this is then considered an invalid GeoJSON object after [rfc7946](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7946) def.

I am using elasticsearch 7.14

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The upper is my answer I receive from elasticsearch. As you can see the "type" is all lowercase. It was indexed in Camelcase, first char uppercase to fit the GeoJSON standard definition. Many libraries consider this as "invalid" GeoJSON. And technically it is.

Answer (score 1):

Use [_search fields API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-fields.html#search-fields-param) to get GeoJson responses with types property capitalized.

Also, in elastic search 7.15, a new [vector tile search API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-vector-tile-api.html) is added that returns search results in vector tile format.